# Freezing bread, sliced or whole

Tags: bread, freezing

I make bread once every 2 weeks for lunch. Is it best to freeze, them slice as quickly as possible and get back into the freezer. Or slice then freeze. Which one keeps it fresher?

Answer (score 5):

This is not that big of a decision.

Two weeks is a short enough time that, if the bread is sealed well and kept frozen, you are unlikely see much of a difference in quality either way.

Sliced bread has more surface area and so doesn't keep as well. Unsliced can be inconvenient to slice when fully frozen.

The worst thing you can do is to let the bread thaw before slicing and refreeze. From your question it seems you recognize this.

If you only plan on consuming a few slices a day and all the bread within two weeks, I would recommend slicing before freezing just for the convenience.

I have done it both ways but usually freeze my loaves whole because we consume them a loaf at a time.